# Google+ Share Button not using specified thumbnail

Tags: google-plus-one

I have a Google+ Share button for each article on my website.

At the moment, when I try to use it, Google+ uses an unrelated image in my document (probably the first one in the document above a certain size) as the thumbnail shown in the feed.

I'd like to specify a thumbnail url to use instead. I used [the +1 button tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/) to generate the proper meta tags, but it just doesn't work. It's still using that unrelated image.

Anyone got it working?

Comment: Did you modify your html element as it says down the bottom of the page? Do you want to give us a link to where you've put it so we can check it?

Comment: Yes, I did! Example article: http://www.indievault.it/2011/09/28/bethesda-vs-mojang-niente-deathmatch-si-va-in-tribunale/

Comment: By the way, one thing to note is that the thumbnail is not included in the article's page as an img tag. The thumbnail for that article I linked should be this one (as shown in the homepage) http://www.indievault.it/wp-content/uploads/thumbs/2011/09/bethmoj_thumb.jpg I don't think this should be a problem, but I'm saying it just to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your specified thumbnail image is not being picked up is because Google+ doesn't like small images (<170px width).

If you link to the full-size image instead of the thumbnail and let G+ do the resizing it will work. I've tested your code with a larger image from your site and it seems to work.

**Reference:**

- [Google Webmaster Central > Share button ignores thumbnail meta-tag - why?](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=4de73da21fbf1673&hl=en#fid_4de73da21fbf16730004abf89bb0089c)

Answer (score 0):

Write an IMG tag  with the right thumb at the beginning of the body and make the the css to display:none

Don't forget that the article thumb may be cached already so it will work only for further articles and/or after cache expiration.

Comment: Tried that too. If you check the HTML in the page I linked in an earlier comment you'll see an img tag with the thumbnail URL and display:none. Not working :( Even tried to add `itemprop="image"` to it, but still not working. It's not the cache either, as I tested it with old (2010) articles.

Comment: Found this : The reason that the +1 Button is not pulling the image marked with the itemprop is because your image resides outside of your itemscope element. If you specify an image inside your article, the +1 Button will pick it up.

SOURCE Jenny Murphy, Google employee : [link](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=4de73da21fbf1673&hl=en)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but what does "inside your article" mean? Do I have to add an attribute to the article's div or something, and then add the itemprop inside this div?

Comment: [Explanations here](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1634179)

Comment: I tried that, but still nothing (added `itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article"` to the body tag and then the image with `itemprop="image"`)

Comment: My message about display:hidden was for another mothod, like for the Facebook button, without taking care of the itemscope properties. Just checked out your page source and you should remove  img you added at the begenning with the display:hidden and add the itemprop="image" to the right thumbnail near your article.  The body is correctly set but i suggest you to try to set also the title and desc itemprop.

Comment: As I said in a comment in my question, the thumbnail is not included in the page as an img tag. Isn't there a way to specify just an URL, just like you can do with Open Graph for Facebook?

Comment: Didn't read that sorry,i guess what you want to achieve is having a general thumbnail for all your pages ? if so put the itemscrope itemtype portion in the html tag instead of body  and add this line in your head section  <link itemprop="image"  rel="image_src" href="/images/mythumb.jpg" >, it work on my site :-)

Comment: I want to have a different thumb for each article. And I tried what you said, but it's still not working. This is driving me nuts! =(

Comment: You may want to fix your isses, open firebug console and load your webpage : "NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://www.indievault.it/wp-content/themes/iv2/images/", you have empty IMG tags, and couple of errors